# Big O Notation For An Algorithm That Contains A Shrinking List Inside While Loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, graph-algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I was trying to estimate the worst case scenario for an algorithm that looks like this (*estimated complexity in comments are mine in which `V` is the number of Vertices and `E` is the number of Edges in a graph*):

```
while(nodes.size()!=0) { // O(V) in which nodes is a LinkedList
     Vertex u = Collections.min(nodes); // O(V)
     nodes.remove(u); // O(1)
     for(Map.Entry<Vertex, Integer> adjacency : u.adj.entrySet()) { // O(E)
         // Some O(1) Statement

         if(nodes.contains(v)) { // O(V)
            // Some O(1) Statement
         }
     }
}
```

My question is very straightforward: 
After every round in the `while` loop, the `nodes` `LinkedList` will go smaller and smaller.
Eventually, both `Collections.min()` and `nodes.contains()` operations will take less time every round.

My understanding is Big O Notation always considers the ***worst***, thus the above complexities should be correct.

Otherwise, would you please explain the plot of how to figure out the correct Complexity in the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodes.contains` has worst-case time complexity in `Θ(V)`, the for-loop runs a number of times in `Θ(E)` and so has worst-case time complexity in `Θ(V*E)`, `Collections.min` has worst-case time complexity in `Θ(V)`, so the body of the while loop has worst-case time complexity in `Θ(V+V*E)`, but `V+V*E` is itself `Θ(V*E)` (see later), so the body of the while loop has worst-case time complexity in `Θ(V*E)`. The while loop executes `V` times. So the worst-case time to execute the algorithm is in `Θ(V^2*E)`.

The simplification there -- replacing `Θ(V+V*E)` with `Θ(V*E)` -- is an acceptable one because we are looking at the general case of `V>1`. That is, `V*E` will always be a bigger number than `V`, so we can absorb `V` into a boundedly constant factor. It would also be correct to say the worst-cast time is in `Θ(V^2+E*V^2)`, but one wouldn't use that since the simplified form is more useful.

Incidentally, as a matter of intuition, you can generally ignore the effect of containers being "used up" during an algorithm, such as with insertion sort having fewer and fewer items to look through, or this algorithm having fewer and fewer nodes to scan. Those effects turn into constant factors and disappear. It's only when you're eliminating an *interesting number* of elements each time, such as with the quickselect algorithm or binary search, that that sort of thing starts to affect the asymptotic runtime.

Comment: Best explanation.. That all I wanted. So We can consider first `V` in `Θ(V+V*E)` as a constant and indeed Big O doesn't take constants into account.

Comment: Yep. Also check my edit, which I think gets to what you were asking about in the question.

Comment: Cheers, so the `nodes` List shrinking effect should not be taken into account as a factor that may change the worst-case complexity as that should be considered constant, Am I right?

Comment: Yep. Again, that's an intuition, not a hard-and-fast rule (though it certainly applies here).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these look correct.  And putting them together you will get time `O(V*(V+E))`.  (Correction, `O((1+E)*V^2)` - I had missed the `O(V)` inside of an `O(E)` inner loop.)

However there is an important correction to your understanding.  Big O notation not always worst case.  The notation is a way of estimating the growth of mathematical functions.  Whether those functions are worst case, or average, or what they measure is entirely up to the problem at hand.  For example quicksort can be implemented in `O(n^2)` worst case running time, with `O(n log(n))` average running time, using `O(log(n))` extra memory on average and `O(n)` extra memory in the worst case.

Comment: Also Shouldn't it be `O(V(V+(E*V)))` -> `O(V^2+EV^2)`?

Comment: @Mike Oops, I had missed that there was an `O(V)` inside of the `O(E)` inner loop.  Which indeed makes it `O((1+E)*V^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the largest possible values at each step but this can give a final value that is too much of an overestimate. To make sure the value is accurate, you can leave taking the upper-bound until the end, but often it ends up being the same anyway.

When the value of `V` changes, then introduce another variable `v` which is the value for one specific iteration. Then the complexity of each iteration is `v+(E*v)`. The total complexity is then the sum of each iteration:

```
sum(v = 1...V) v+(E*v)
= 1+1E + 2+2E + 3+3E + ... + V+VE                 - Expand the sum
= (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + V) + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + V)E  - Regroup terms
= (V^2 + V)/2 + (V^2 + V)E/2                      - Sum of arithmetic series
= (V^2 + V + EV^2 + EV)/2                         - Addition of fractions
= O(EV^2)                                         - EV^2 greater than all other terms
```